# Number validation in html form on input of type number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am thinking all possibilities that a user can enters into a `<input>` of type number and using jquery to validate the input.

In the input field, I put in just a simple dot '.'

```
if($("#timetaken").val() == "")
```

and this if statement executed with the response saying it is empty. There is a '.' dot in it and logically speaking it should skip this and execute the else that tells us it is not empty.

I also tested with the input "1." that is incomplete with

```
console.log($("#timetaken").val().toString().indexOf("."));
```

and it returns -1, which means the '.' is not there and ignored.

The question is there a way to validate these two inputs in an `<input>` tag of type number?

Thank you.

Comment: I might suggest running `debugger;` in the event handler and taking a look at the `e.target.validity` property.  There appear to be some properties in there that may be able to give you some information about what the user entered, without actually telling you what they entered.

Comment: I think regex might be a better solution for me. Should have thought of that.

Comment: I think you should include your exact HTML in the question — is it `<input type="number" ...>` (as I assume it is, based on your statement "of type number") or is it `<input type="text" ...>` **?** I think my assumption is correct based on what you write, but don't leave me to make assumptions; be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to test a `number` input with some non-number characters (like a single dot).. Yes, sure the empty passes.

I would suggest you to use a `text` input with a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to test the value as you wish. This input type has no strange behavior or restriction and a "regex" can **exactly** test the value for whatever requirement you have.

That would be (from what I can read from your question) something like:

```js
$("#go").on("click",function(){
  var value = $("#test").val();
  var regex = /((\d){1,9}\.?\d*)|(\d*\.?(\d){1,9})/;  // {1,9} means at least 1 and up to 9 digits.
  if(regex.test(value)){
    console.log("Value is ok");
  }else{
    console.log("Value fails.");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="test"> <button id="go">Test</button>
```

So floating numbers or natural numbers are ok.
Nothing else.

Regex tester: [regex101](https://regex101.com/).